# 404 HTTP Response using HttpWebRequest for a HTTPS url working with browsers

Tags: .net, curl, https, httpwebrequest

The site is `https://www.orias.fr`. It seems to be using tls 1.2 and redirects to the `/welcome` page.

Here's a piece of code to check its accessibility (**.NET 4.5**) :

```
Private Function getURLStatus() As String

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.Tls12
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.orias.fr")
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = Nothing

    Try
        resp = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Catch ex As WebException
        resp = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse)
        If resp Is Nothing Then Return ex.Message
    End Try

    Return CInt(resp.StatusCode)

End Function
```

This gives me a `404` HTTP response.

Also, I tried to access this url with  **`cURL`** (7.54.1 - Cygwin, output is pasted below). After some handshakes lines, I noticed this:

```
$ curl -vA "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0" 'https://www.orias.fr'
[...]
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
    < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

But **`cURL`** is able to "overcome" this response and gets the web content. How can I do this in my code ?

**`cURL` output :**

```
$ curl -vA "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0" 'https://www.orias.fr'
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x600057930; line 1410 (connection #-5000)
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.orias.fr/
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x600057930; line 1446 (connection #0)
*   Trying 160.92.131.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x600057930; line 1527 (connection #0)
* Connected to www.orias.fr (160.92.131.100) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057930; line 1579 (connection #0)
* Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057930; line 1593 (connection #0)
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=FR; L=Paris; O=ORIAS; CN=orias.fr
*  start date: Mar 31 13:49:03 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 28 14:19:02 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.orias.fr" matched cert's "www.orias.fr"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms; OU=(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x600057930; line 1614 (connection #0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.orias.fr
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
> Accept: */*
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x600057930; line 1676 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x600057930; line 1801 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x600057930; line 1811 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Thu, 21 Dec 2017 18:45:04 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=51A18E34C2884CDF4FBC71CE98CDD400.B8D1472E80D54428AFD2557FEED2; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
[HTML content]
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the HTML returned by **`cURL`** for [https//www.orias.fr](https://www.orias.fr) contains only a redirection:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta content="1; url=/c" http-equiv="refresh" />
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:location.replace('/c')">
        <!-- truncated irrelevant content (fills up space for IE) -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The browsers performs a redirection to `/c` through `<meta>` element or through Javascript. **`cURL`** shows a 302 redirection for the `/c` url:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
[...]
< Location: https://www.orias.fr/c/portal/layout
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html
```

Then **`cURL`** shows for `/c/portal/layout`:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
[...]
< Location: https://www.orias.fr/welcome
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

And then, at last, `/welcome` returns `200`.

**TL;DR:** to check if an URL is "human" valid, act like a "real" browser.